# Rx IObservable produce value only when value has changed by a certain margin

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I have a feeling this might be a very simple Extension method that I have missed but I can't see to find it...

I basically want to take a stream that produces a stream where the value slowly incrementing upon each new value.  I want to Throttle/Sample this, not by time, but by "tolerance".  e.g.

```
var ob = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).ToObservable(); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,....., 30
var largeMovingOb = ob.WhenChangedBy(10); // 0, 10, 20, 30
```

when I have sequences such as [1, 4, 20, 33] and I want to output when value has changed by more than 15 of the last one - which would result in: [1, 20]. Where as a change by value of 12 would result in: [1, 20, 33]

Is there a built-in Rx extension for this?  Ideally it would work on all numeric types without writing an overload for each.

Comment: So you want an Observable that fires only when the value changes by more than X?

Comment: Yes but not just from the last value yielded by the source, but the value last yielded.  See comment  to @jeroenh below.

Comment: Do you know that you can do `var ob = Observable.Range(0, 30);`?

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity.  Didn't know that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a good fit for `Observable.Scan`

```
var ob = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).ToObservable();
var largeMovingOb = ob.Scan((acc, i) => acc + 10 > i ? acc : i)
  .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Comment: +1; elegant solution that satisfies the specs without ugly hacks

Answer (score 0):

Another built in operator you could repurpose is [DistinctUntilChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229776%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), which will keep track of the last value for you.  The biggest "hack" here is that the `IEqualityComparer` may not follow the standard expectations of equality (`a == b && b == c` does not imply `a == c` depending on the function)

```
public static IObservable<T> DistinctUntilChangedBy<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> isChanged)
{
    //check arguments
    return source.DistinctUntilChanged(new MarginEqualityComparer<T>(isChanged));
}

class MarginEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    MarginEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _comparer;

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _comparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This comparer does not support hashing.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in operator that does what you want.

Try this:

```
var ob = Observable.Range(0, 30);
var largeMovingOb = ob.DistinctUntilChanged(x => x / 10);
```

It'll work any type, not just numeric types, as the signature looks like this:

```
IObservable<TSource> DistinctUntilChanged<TSource, TKey>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

Simple.

Comment: While the example assumes values that increment by 1 and starts from 0, your solution *only* works for that case.  If there is a skip larger than one or the seed value is not 0, then this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211607%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx), keeping track of what you last yielded and having the predicate return true only when the value has exceeded the last yielded value by the tolerance level.

This can be wrapped into an extension method that takes advantage of closures to do this, like so:

```
public static IObservable<int> WhenLastObservedChangesByMoreThan(
    this IObservable<int> observable, int tolerance)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (observable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("observable");

    // Tolerance must be positive, so comparisons are correct after
    // addition/subtraction.
    if (tolerance < 0) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeExeption("tolerance", tolerance,
            "The tolerance parameter must be a non-negative number.");

    // Shortcut: If tolerance is 0, then every value is returned, just
    // return the observable.
    if (tolerance == 0) return observable;

    // The last value yielded.
    int? lastYielded = null;

    // Filter.
    observable = observable.Where(i => {
        // If there is a previous value
        // that was yielded.
        if (lastYielded != null)
        {
            // Is the last value within
            // tolerance?
            if (i - tolerance < i && i < i + tolerance)
            {
                // Do not process.
                return false;
            }
        }

        // This is being yielded, store the value.
        lastYielded = i;

        // Yield the value.
        return true;
    });
}
```

Note that the above is not thread-safe, if your `IObservable<T>` is calling [`OnNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782792.aspx) from multiple threads then you'll have to lock access to the `lastYielded` variable (which is easy enough to do with a [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)).